# Natural Isomorphism $(Y^Z)^X\cong Y^{Z\times X}$ in a cartesian closed category

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cartesian closed category. I'm working on a problem that asks me to show that for $X,Y,Z\in\text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ there is a natural isomorphism $(Y^Z)^X\cong Y^{Z\times X}$. It's easy enough to show the two are isomorphic as objects of $\mathcal{C}$ by showing one satisfies the universal property of the other, but I not sure what is the correct perspective to show neutrality. Do we want to show isomorphism of functors $(Y^{-})^{-},Y^{-\times -}\colon \mathcal{C}^\text{op}\times \mathcal{C}^\text{op}\to \mathcal{C}$? Or is it an isomorphism between $(-^-)^X$ and $(-)^{-\times X}$?

I know one can prove this using the fact that the $(-)^X$ is right adjoint to $-\times X$, but I am interested in explicitly constructing the isomorphism.

Comment: Naturality is true in *all three* variables. It's actually a bit tricky to even state this properly since two are contravariant and one is covariant, but see: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extranatural+transformation

Comment: Before you can have a natural isomorphism you have to have a functor. How have you made exponentiation a functor? The proof will depend on the definition!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That seems a bit over my head at the moment, but thank you for the reference!

Comment: @ZhenLin If $g\colon Y\to Y'$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ then $g^X\colon Y^X\to (Y')^X$ is the unique morphism such that $\text{ev}_{Y'}\circ g^X\times 1_X=f\circ\text{ev}_Y$. Similarly if $f\colon X\to X'$ then $Y^f\colon Y^{X'}\to Y^X$ is the uniqe map such that $\text{ev}_Y\circ Y^f\times 1_X=\text{ev}_Y\circ 1_{Y^{X'}}\times f$